# How to load products media gallery along with the collection?

Tags: magento

Can anybody give me a hint about how to load product's media gallery along with the collection?

I'm getting the collection like this:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    var_dump($product->getMediaGalleryImages());
}
```

But getMediaGalleryImages() returns `null`. I know that I can load each product separately with `$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId())` but I want to avoid this, because it causing unnecessary workload.

Answer (score -6, accepted):

Here is a function to add the media gallery to a collection:

```
// Source: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/17414/#t141830

public function addMediaGalleryAttributeToCollection(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection $_productCollection) {
    $_mediaGalleryAttributeId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'media_gallery')->getAttributeId();
    $_read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('catalog_read');

    $_mediaGalleryData = $_read->fetchAll('
        SELECT
            main.entity_id, `main`.`value_id`, `main`.`value` AS `file`,
            `value`.`label`, `value`.`position`, `value`.`disabled`, `default_value`.`label` AS `label_default`,
            `default_value`.`position` AS `position_default`,
            `default_value`.`disabled` AS `disabled_default`
        FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AS `main`
            LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AS `value`
                ON main.value_id=value.value_id AND value.store_id=' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() . '
            LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AS `default_value`
                ON main.value_id=default_value.value_id AND default_value.store_id=0
        WHERE (
            main.attribute_id = ' . $_read->quote($_mediaGalleryAttributeId) . ') 
            AND (main.entity_id IN (' . $_read->quote($_productCollection->getAllIds()) . '))
        ORDER BY IF(value.position IS NULL, default_value.position, value.position) ASC    
    ');

    $_mediaGalleryByProductId = array();
    foreach ($_mediaGalleryData as $_galleryImage) {
        $k = $_galleryImage['entity_id'];
        unset($_galleryImage['entity_id']);
        if (!isset($_mediaGalleryByProductId[$k])) {
            $_mediaGalleryByProductId[$k] = array();
        }
        $_mediaGalleryByProductId[$k][] = $_galleryImage;
    }
    unset($_mediaGalleryData);
    foreach ($_productCollection as &$_product) {
        $_productId = $_product->getData('entity_id');
        if (isset($_mediaGalleryByProductId[$_productId])) {
            $_product->setData('media_gallery', array('images' => $_mediaGalleryByProductId[$_productId]));
        }
    }
    unset($_mediaGalleryByProductId);

    return $_productCollection;
}
```

An example of it's usage below:

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*');
$this->addMediaGalleryToArray($products);
```

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20120514004308/http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/17414/P0/

Comment: @janw what about crappy magento itself?

Answer (score 18):

In case anyone’s looking for another approach on this, I found this to work (in just one case so no guarantees!):

Be sure to do `$collection->addAttributeToSelect(’image’);` first, then when looping through the collection products, do:

```
$attributes = $product->getTypeInstance(true)->getSetAttributes($product);
$media_gallery = $attributes[’media_gallery’];
$backend = $media_gallery->getBackend();
$backend->afterLoad($product); //this loads the media gallery to the product object
```

Not sure if all of this is necessary but I’m in a hurry. In my particular case I was trying to get the image url using `$product->getImageUrl();` and this approach worked for me.

Hope it helps someone else.

Comment: **Important note on performance:** The `afterLoad()` is actually pretty fast. Getting the $backend isn't. The $backend Variable actually should be the same for all products so it can be cached.

Comment: Further to Alex's comment, we found that `getSetAttributes($product)` takes around 50ms to load.  For us this is an issue because we have many products loading so 50ms is significant.  If you cache (only run them for the first product) the first 3 lines rather than just the `getBackend` line then performance (at least for us) is significantly increased.

Answer (score 11):

I had to do the same recently, fastest method:

```
class My_Module_Block_Name extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Abstract
{

/** @var null|Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute */
protected static $_mediaGalleryBackend = null;

public function getGalleryImages()
{
    $product = $this->getProduct();
    $this->_getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
    $collection = $product->getMediaGalleryImages();

    return $collection;
}


/**
 * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute
 */
protected function _getBackend() {
    if (self::$_mediaGalleryBackend === null) {

        $mediaGallery = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')
            ->getAttribute(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product::ENTITY, 'media_gallery');

        self::$_mediaGalleryBackend = $mediaGallery->getBackend();
    }

    return self::$_mediaGalleryBackend;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                        ->addStoreFilter($storeId)
                        ->addAttributeToSelect(array('image', 'media_gallery'))
                        ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    var_dump($product->getMediaGallery());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It can be used directly in loop:

```
foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $product->getResource()->getAttribute('media_gallery')->getBackend()->afterLoad($product);
    foreach ($product->getMediaGalleryImages() as $image) {
        var_dump($image->debug());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are going to have to use:

```
// Returns the Media Gallery Images
Mage::getModel(’catalog/product’)->load(productid)->getMediaGalleryImages();
```

**Reference**: http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/29639/

Comment: It loads whole product. Yes, it works but it takes a lot of time and memory.

Comment: Whats is your recommended solution?

Answer (score 0):

The secret sauce when working with custom collections involving products is the third parameter of `init` method... at least it was for me. **This way I don't need to load the whole product and run expensive queries**.

So, having my custom `$product` which represents an instance of `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product` but from my custom collection, I can do:

```php
(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image', $product->getImage())
```

I also needed to add the `image` attribute to my custom collection, and I did that by adding `->addAttributeToSelect(['image'])` to it.

You can also resize your image accordingly:

```php
(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'small_image', $product->getImage())->resize($width, $height=null)
```