# Get Product Media Gallery Images from a Product Collection in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I have a collection of products in Magento that I would like to be able to get the media gallery images out of. However I am finding that I have to iterate though my collection and load the product again to get the getMediaGalleryImages() function to work properly.

```
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
    ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', 4)
    ->addAttributeToFilter('status', 1);

foreach($products as $product) {
    $_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product->getId());

    $product->getMediaGalleryImages();      // This returns nothing
    $_product->getMediaGalleryImages();     // Returns the Collection of Images
}
```

Obviously I could continue just reloading the product each time, but that would add quite a bit of overhead to the time required to run this code.

Is there a way to add in the media gallery images to the collection?

Comment: you can do a join : mediagallerycollection -> join productcollection where productId -s in(id,id,id,id). As there is usually more than one image per product you can't just join them to productcollection

Comment: This question was answered in another post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900522/how-to-load-products-media-gallery-along-with-the-collection

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to load products media gallery along with the collection?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5900522/how-to-load-products-media-gallery-along-with-the-collection)

Answer (score 18):

You can use

```
$product->load('media_gallery');
```

before getMediaGalleryImages (on the products you loaded in the collection).

Comment: strangely, this works. The magic happens in Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->load($object, $entityId, $attributes). If $attributes is empty it will call loadAllAttribute($object). So $product->load('blah') will load all missing attributes, including 'media_gallery'

Comment: So does this load an individual product?

If so, then it's prohibitive to use this for large numbers of products, and nullifies the benefit of using collections.

Comment: Magic ! it worked. if you are using for somewhere in product image upload just make sure to save product before using this.

Comment: yes this load the entire product so this answer is totally wrong for 2 reason:
1. it obvious that loading the entire product you get also the media gallery, 2.  the function load is used the wrong way

Answer (score 7):

One simple method for future reference:

Outside your foreach add

```
$mediaBackend = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_attribute_backend_media');
$mediaGalleryAttribute = Mage::getModel('eav/config')->getAttribute(Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId(), 'media_gallery');
$mediaBackend->setAttribute($mediaGalleryAttribute);
```

and then do the foreach:

```
foreach ($productCollection as $product) {
    $mediaBackend->afterLoad($product);
}
```

You will have then the gallery loaded on product.

Answer (score 3):

load product's cached image using collection by following codes

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135);
```

//or

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'thumbnail')->resize(135);
```

//or

```
Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image')->resize(135);
```

this is the collection which i used

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToSelect('small_image') //or
        ->addAttributeToSelect('thumbnail')  //or
        ->addAttributeToSelect('image');
```

Comment: this do not load the media gallery but only the 3 main images ( small, thumb, main image )

Answer (score 1):

You can create a helper class, and use it every time you need media gallery images to be loaded for a collection of products:

```
class My_Package_Helper_Media extends Mage_Core_Helper_Abstract {
    public function addMediaGalleryAttributeToProductCollection( &$productCollection )
    {
        $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();

        $ids = array();
        foreach ( $productCollection as $product ) {
            $ids[] = $product->getEntityId();
        }

        $resource = Mage::getSingleton( 'core/resource' );
        $conn = Mage::getSingleton( 'core/resource' )->getConnection( 'catalog_read' );
        $select = $conn->select()
            ->from(
                   array( 'mg' => $resource->getTableName( 'catalog/product_attribute_media_gallery' ) ),
                   array(
                         'mg.entity_id', 'mg.attribute_id', 'mg.value_id', 'file' => 'mg.value',
                         'mgv.label', 'mgv.position', 'mgv.disabled',
                         'label_default' => 'mgdv.label',
                         'position_default' => 'mgdv.position',
                         'disabled_default' => 'mgdv.disabled'
                         )
                   )
            ->joinLeft(
                       array( 'mgv' => $resource->getTableName( 'catalog/product_attribute_media_gallery_value' ) ),
                       '(mg.value_id=mgv.value_id AND mgv.store_id=' . $storeId . ')',
                       array()
                       )
            ->joinLeft(
                       array( 'mgdv' => $resource->getTableName( 'catalog/product_attribute_media_gallery_value' ) ),
                       '(mg.value_id=mgdv.value_id AND mgdv.store_id=0)',
                       array()
                       )
            ->where( 'entity_id IN(?)', $ids );

        $mediaGalleryByProductId = array();

        $stmt = $conn->query( $select );
        while ( $gallery = $stmt->fetch() ) {
            $k = $gallery[ 'entity_id' ];
            unset( $gallery[ 'entity_id' ] );
            if ( !isset($mediaGalleryByProductId[$k]) ) {
                $mediaGalleryByProductId[$k] = array();
            }
            $mediaGalleryByProductId[$k][] = $gallery;
        }
        unset( $stmt ); // finalize statement

        // Updating collection ...
        foreach ( $productCollection as &$product ) {
            $productId = $product->getEntityId();
            if ( isset( $mediaGalleryByProductId[ $productId ] ) ) {
                $product->setData( 'media_gallery', array( 'images' => $mediaGalleryByProductId[ $productId ] ) );
            }
        }
        unset( $mediaGalleryByProductId );
    }
}
```

Sample usage:

```
$coll = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
    ->setStoreId( Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() )
    ->addAttributeToFilter( 'sku', array( 'in' => array( 'AAA', 'BBB' ) ) );
Mage::helper('my_package/media')->addMediaGalleryAttributeToProductCollection( $coll );
```

Answer (score -5):

Here the code you were looking for, sorry for the delay :)

It come from this discussion:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/17414/

I just added some extra check on the number of id a and pagination

```
function addMediaGalleryAttributeToCollection(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Product_Collection $_productCollection)
{
    if (Mage::getStoreConfig('color_selector_plus/colorselectorplusgeneral/showonlist', Mage::app()->getStore())) {

        $_mediaGalleryAttributeId = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'media_gallery')->getAttributeId();
        $_read = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource')->getConnection('catalog_read');

        $pageCur = $_productCollection->getCurPage();
        $pageSize = $_productCollection->getPageSize();
        $offset = $pageSize * ($pageCur - 1);

        $ids = $_productCollection->getAllIds($pageSize, $offset);

        // added check on products number: if 0 ids the following query breaks
        if (count($ids) > 0) {

            $sql = '
    SELECT
        main.entity_id, `main`.`value_id`, `main`.`value` AS `file`, `value`.`disabled`,
        /*`value`.`label`, `value`.`position`, */
       /*`default_value`.`label` AS `label_default`, */
       /*`default_value`.`position` AS `position_default`, */
        `default_value`.`disabled` AS `disabled_default`
    FROM `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery` AS `main`
        LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AS `value`
            ON main.value_id=value.value_id AND value.store_id=' . Mage::app()->getStore()->getId() . '
        LEFT JOIN `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` AS `default_value`
            ON main.value_id=default_value.value_id AND default_value.store_id=0
    WHERE (
        main.attribute_id = ' . $_read->quote($_mediaGalleryAttributeId) . ')
        AND (main.entity_id IN (' . $_read->quote($_productCollection->getAllIds()) . '))
    /*ORDER BY IF(value.position IS NULL, default_value.position, value.position) ASC */
';
            $_mediaGalleryData = $_read->fetchAll($sql);


            $_mediaGalleryByProductId = array();
            foreach ($_mediaGalleryData as $_galleryImage) {
                $k = $_galleryImage['entity_id'];
                unset($_galleryImage['entity_id']);
                if (!isset($_mediaGalleryByProductId[$k])) {
                    $_mediaGalleryByProductId[$k] = array();
                }
                $_mediaGalleryByProductId[$k][] = $_galleryImage;
            }
            unset($_mediaGalleryData);
            foreach ($_productCollection as &$_product) {
                $_productId = $_product->getData('entity_id');
                if (isset($_mediaGalleryByProductId[$_productId])) {
                    $_product->setData('media_gallery', array('images' => $_mediaGalleryByProductId[$_productId]));
                }
            }
            unset($_mediaGalleryByProductId);
        }
    }
    return $_productCollection;
}
```

Comment: take care that info relative to label and default value has been commented in the query

Comment: I'm extending an extension so that we can feature products on the Magento homepage and am wondering where I can implement this code so that we can [load a product's gallery images with the collection at homepage](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17812658/getgalleryimages-returning-null-in-magento-homepage). Unsure whether we'd have to add this function to the model or run from template file.

Comment: you can override this class Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List ... or put it in any class related to your template ... you just need to pass the collection to it and it should do the job ... up vote is always welcome ;)

Comment: I agree, anyway it works and it is faster that load the product. ( I am surprised this answer was downvoted while there are at least 2 answer totally wrong but with high score )